# How do I import and export files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, babeljs, requirejs

I created a separate file for a function and exported it to my main file to use by "import Header from "./Header.js";" but it is throwing error that "require is not defined" and "Module name "Header" has not been loaded yet for context".[importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cr5V.png)[exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gp4.png)[html doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa7Kc.png)[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eziy1.png)

I expected the html code to run smoothly and display my web page but its all blank at the moment.

Comment: Please post code snippets in the question instead of adding images. It helps others to debug better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

`const Header = "./Header.js";`

`instead of import Header from "./Header.js"`